# Removing headers from .csv using Powershell then saving the .csv

Tags: powershell

Ok, first off I am a absolute total noob with PS so I apologize for my ignorance now.

I have a .csv file which I am importing and (I believe) am stripping out the headers which is what I want, I am then trying to save it again as the same .csv

here is what I am using to import it into PS, and the on screen input does not show the headers so I know the -Skip 1 is working and for my education I played with that value and it's working.

```
$file = "C:PATH\Okta NO 2K.csv"
$data = import-csv $file
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

What I am having issues with is how to then export the data back into a .csv with the only change being the headers being removed. A few things I have done has change the format from data in every tab (every cell) to various tables which is not what I need. I appreciate any help.

Comment: If the operation you need is to remove the first line of the file, then you do not need to import it as a CSV file: just regard it as a plain text file and skip the first line. Unless one of the header fields could have a newline in it.

Comment: Andrew's suggested approach is the best under the circumstances, but the only thing missing from your code is to append a `Set-Content` call to the pipeline in order to write the results to a file (use `-Encoding` as needed).

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, I am not totally sure what Andrew was talking about so I just appended as Mklement0 suggested, worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Jason. Wasif's answer below shows what @AndrewMorton meant. Note that in order for others to be notified of follow-up comments, you must @-mention them (as I have done here with Andrew's username), though you can only mention _one_ user explicitly (a post's author is implicitly notified).

Answer (score 1):

I can use this:

```
(get-content $file)|select -skip 1|set-content $file
```

As the suggestion by @Andrew

But the only problem is that here whenever you will import the modified csv it will take the first row as header, so it could not be imported without headers. So you need a duplicate header using `-Header` or other things

Note the need to use `()` to enclose `get-content` so that it reads the whole file into memory first, which is required if you want to save back to the same file as part of the same command.